# Python ftplib only uploads some files, but not all

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I try to upload some files to a ftp server within the same network. The script is started every hour, but some files just remain in the folder and won't get uploaded even if I start the script manually.

The files have this format:

```
20150918-232105-479.jpg
```

and a corresponding png file, with only the last part of the jpg-filename:

```
479.png
```

The problem is somewhere in the for loop. It just enters the for-loop once, even if I have a lot more files in the directory and in `filelist`

```
import ftplib
import os
import sys
import time
import glob
from datetime import datetime

ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("192.168.0.9", 21)
print(ftp.getwelcome())
try:
    print "Logging in..."
    ftp.login("someuser", "somepassword")
    filelist = []
    for file in os.listdir("/home/kamera"):
            if file.endswith('.jpg'):
                filelist.append(file)
                print(file)

    for item in filelist:
        f = open(item, 'rb')

        temp = item.split('-')[0]
        endung = (item.split('-')[2])

        png = endung[:-3] + 'png'
        pngf = open(png, 'rb')

        if(temp in ftp.nlst()):
            ftp.cwd(temp)
        else:
            print(temp)
            ftp.mkd(temp)
            ftp.cwd(temp)

        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + endung, f)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + png, pngf)     

        print(str(item) + " stored")
        ftp.cwd('/')
        f.close()
        pngf.close()
        pfad = os.getcwd() + '/' + str(item)
        pfadpng = os.getcwd() + '/' + str(png)

        os.remove(pfad)
        os.remove(pfadpng)

    ftp.quit()

except:
    "failed to login"
```

Comment: You missed an indentation.

Comment: Check `.endswith('.jpg')`

Comment: Thanks, this happened while copying the text, in the orgiginal file the intendation is there.

Comment: Why did you mixed print statements from python2 & python3?  I see print as function and statement both in code.

Comment: just lazyness I guess. I run it with python2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90105/discussion-between-akash-shende-and-user3549596).

Comment: Does it, by any chance, print "failed to login" a lot? You've wrapped every single error it could produce in the big `try: ... except:... ` block, hidden every error and replaced it with "failed to login". I guess it's getting a file not found, or a permission denied, or an FTP error, and failing part way through but you never find out what happens.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, this was the case. A corresponding png file was missing, resulting in an IOError.